# Android: How get the status-code of an HttpClient request

Tags: android, httpclient, httprequest, http-status-codes

I want to download a file and need to check the response status code (ie `HTTP /1.1 200 OK`).
This is a snipped of my code:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(myUri);
HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
...
```

How do i get the status-code of the response?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

This will return the `int` value:

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Comment: Then you can compare with the HTTP status codes http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html

Comment: Since HttpStatus is a deprecated class is there a better class to be used?

Comment: @AkashRamani - Yes, just use the HttpUrlConnection method: .getResponseCode()

Comment: @NikitaKurtin sure that returns an integer but how would you know what the actual response code's Http Response Status is? How would you know if its successful? I dont want to say `if(getResponseCode()==200)`.
I'd rather say `if(getResponseCode()==HttpStatus.RESPONSE_OK)` or something like that.

Comment: @AkashRamani, Yes, it has int Constants inside the class for that.
for example 
HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK (200 -> http ok status)
HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND (404 -> not found), 
etc..

full list of available constants you can find in it's class reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_ACCEPTED

Answer (score 11):

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `code()` function of response to get its HTTP code:

```
val code = response.code()
```