# Android WebViewClient, onErrorReceived not being called when there is a 404

Tags: android

I've got a WebView, with a WebViewClient that defines onErrorReceived, and onPageFinished.

The onPageFinished gets called correctly, so I know that the WebViewclient is attached to the WebView correctly.  However, there's some javascript in the WebView that calls:

`location.href="http://kernel.org/asdf/asdf/asdf/asdf";`

And the onErrorReceived listener is not called, even though it's a 404.  Does it not work with javascript calls?

Edit: After some testing, I have found that NO 404s are reported to this function whatsoever.  I have a test project set up here:  http://vimtips.org/media/WebViewTest.zip

It appears that this method cannot be used to test for 404s.  Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: It can't be done with WebView, you can however use the basic HTTPClient and check for the response code. Here is a link on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592843/android-how-get-the-status-code-of-an-httpclient-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done.  At least, not in a non-hacky way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2):

In following [situation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#constants), onErrorReceived will be called.

- ERROR_AUTHENTICATION  User authentication failed on server
- ERROR_BAD_URL Malformed URL
- ERROR_CONNECT Failed to connect to the server
- ERROR_FAILED_SSL_HANDSHAKE    Failed to perform SSL handshake
- ERROR_FILE    Generic file error
- ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  File not found
- ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP Server or proxy hostname lookup failed
- ERROR_IO  Failed to read or write to the server
- ERROR_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION    User authentication failed on proxy
- ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP   Too many redirects
- ERROR_TIMEOUT Connection timed out
- ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS   Too many requests during this load
- ERROR_UNKNOWN Generic error
- ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_AUTH_SCHEME Unsupported authentication scheme (not basic or digest)
- ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME  Unsupported URI scheme

Actually, none of HTTP response codes are in the list above.