# Android HttpResponse response Code

Tags: android, http

I am trying to get the response code for the HttpReponse. There is no method for get the response code directly.

Comment: Good question but already asked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[HttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode%28%29) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the link [Android: How get the status-code of an HttpClient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592843/android-how-get-the-status-code-of-an-httpclient-request)

Hopefully, it will help you.

Regards,

Android Geek.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get Response code if you are using `HttpUrlConnection` :

```
int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
Log.i("", "Status : " + status);
```

And here is if you are using `HttpClient` :

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.getStatusLine().toString());
```