# how to get/ask only status code for a httpRequest with android?

Tags: android, http-status-codes, http-request

My question is pretty similar to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592843/android-how-get-the-status-code-of-an-httpclient-request) 
except but I need only the header of the response in order to reduce battery consomation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a HEAD request. In the http protocol this will return to you only the Header of the response.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4

This can be done in android using [HttpHead](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [HttpHead](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead.html) request

Comment: snap ;-) why is it answering on SO always feels like a race?

Comment: since the active order, mine is older. If you prefer I can delete the question