# Using AndroidHttpClient will not work

Tags: android

I am trying to use `AndroidHttpClient` to download a CSV file. For some reason it fails in the line `"HttpResponse response httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);` and simply goes to `"finally"`.

I've checked the URL in my browser - it is working fine.

I get no information from HttpResponse response - it simply like skips it.

I don't get why. Any ideas?

Thanks
D

```
private ArrayList<String> retrieveStockFinParamsFromYahooApiUri(String yahooApiCall)
    {
        ArrayList<String> stockFinParamsFromYahooApiUriRows = new ArrayList<String>();
        String resultLine = "";

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("yahooGetStockParams");
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(yahooApiCall);

        try 
        {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);              

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            while ((resultLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                stockFinParamsFromYahooApiUriRows.add(resultLine);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (reader != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    reader.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return stockFinParamsFromYahooApiUriRows;
    }
```

---

FURTHER INVESTIGATION (05.22.2012):

@Snicolas - thank you for your comments. After I read your comments I thought the problem might originate from the fact that I used the emulator and not my actual device to debug this. I thought the emulator might suffer some connection problems. When I tested it on my device - I noticed the problem still occurred - so this was NOT the problem.

So I change my code to `catch (Throwable e)` as you advised and got the following stack snapshot:

```
05-22 18:17:41.457: W/System.err(24552): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-22 18:17:41.461: W/System.err(24552):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
05-22 18:17:41.461: W/System.err(24552):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
05-22 18:17:41.461: W/System.err(24552):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
05-22 18:17:41.465: W/System.err(24552):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
05-22 18:17:41.465: W/System.err(24552):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-22 18:17:41.465: W/System.err(24552):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-22 18:17:41.468: W/System.err(24552):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-22 18:17:41.468: W/System.err(24552):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-22 18:17:41.468: W/System.err(24552):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-22 18:17:41.472: W/System.err(24552):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-22 18:17:41.472: W/System.err(24552):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
05-22 18:17:41.472: W/System.err(24552):    at com.bewildering.app.StournamentDbAdapter$YahooStocksParams.retrieveStockFinParamsFromYahooApiUri(StournamentDbAdapter.java:1536)
05-22 18:17:41.476: W/System.err(24552):    at com.bewildering.app.StournamentDbAdapter$YahooStocksParams.run(StournamentDbAdapter.java:1709)
05-22 18:17:41.476: W/System.err(24552):    at com.bewildering.app.StournamentActivity.onCreate(StournamentActivity.java:65)
05-22 18:17:41.476: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-22 18:17:41.476: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-22 18:17:41.480: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-22 18:17:41.480: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-22 18:17:41.480: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-22 18:17:41.484: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-22 18:17:41.484: W/System.err(24552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 18:17:41.484: W/System.err(24552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 18:17:41.484: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-22 18:17:41.488: W/System.err(24552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 18:17:41.488: W/System.err(24552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 18:17:41.488: W/System.err(24552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-22 18:17:41.492: W/System.err(24552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-22 18:17:41.492: W/System.err(24552):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

While looking for `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`I found [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) which states that this is: *The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.*

From that I conclude that I should put my call into an `AsyncTask`.

Can anyone please confirm that I understand this correctly - or am I missing something here? Strange that I hat to `catch (Throwable e)` in order to get to the bottom of this.

---

FURTHER INVESTIGATION (05.22.2012):

I can now confirm that this issue comes due to the fact that *The exception... is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.* As I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception) this started with honeycomb.

Ths issue now: I get a 301 response from Yahoo (Moved Permanently). This is strange because when I cut paste the URL into the browser it works.

Any idea why this should work in the browser but not in the application? I must mention that this HTTP request receives a CSV file as a response. Could this be an issue?

---

FURTHER INVESTIGATION (05.23.2012):

For some reason when using (in my code) the Yahoo URI http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s= the response is a 301 (Moved Permanently). When using http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s= instead the response is 200 (OK). Even that both work fine in the browser. I was lucky enough to find [this web page](http://help.infinitekind.com/discussions/moneydance-development/14-stock-quote-synchronizer-for-stock-options) that gave me some clues regarding which URIs Yahoo reacts to. Now I can see the "reader" gets the data and everything is ALMOST fine. I still get some strange exception (still trying to figure it out): after reading all the lines in the response I catch a Throwable (I left it from my previous experiments) and later on in the stack I thus get `05-23 08:52:41.258: W/dalvikvm(933): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a721f8)` and something about an uncaught exception in `doInBackground(Void... params)`. Still investigating...

Just solved this issue - it was just a mistake in calling the Yahoo API. Had to add **&e=.csv** to the end of the URI for it to work. Just like that: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=KDHIX&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv

---

FINAL CODE

```
private ArrayList<String> retrieveStockFinParamsFromYahooApiUri(String yahooApiCall)
    {
        ArrayList<String> stockFinParamsFromYahooApiUriRows = new ArrayList<String>();
        String resultLine = "";

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("yahooGetStockParams");
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(yahooApiCall);

        try 
        {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);                  

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            while ((resultLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                stockFinParamsFromYahooApiUriRows.add(resultLine);
            }

            if(response != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    response.getEntity().consumeContent();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } 
        finally 
        {               
            if(httpClient != null)
            {
                httpClient.close();
            }

            if (reader != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    reader.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return stockFinParamsFromYahooApiUriRows;
    }
```

Comment: you should edit your post and add here full error log. But it seems like error in connection. check httpResponseCode and it must return HTTP_OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that you get an `Exception` in execute that is not an `IOException`. Then, your `catch` block never get executed and your `finally` block is executed before the method throws an exepected exception to the caller of `retrieveStockFinParamsFromYahooApiUri`.

You have at least 2 options :

- don't catch an `IOException` but a prent class. Try `Throwable`, print the stack trace and see what happens. Then you can later add other catch blocks to handle the case. ([*Catching `Throwables` is a bad programming practice*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-the-throwable), but you can use temporarily).
- place the invocation of `retrieveStockFinParamsFromYahooApiUri` in a try catch block using the same mechanism as above to determine which exception classes to expect and act accordingly.

But you need to refine your understanding of the problem, catch everything possible, write the stack trace and check the logcat.

**Here are some other advices :**

- You need to [check the result code of the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592843/android-how-get-the-status-code-of-an-httpclient-request) before reading its content.
- You could use [Apache IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.Reader,%20java.io.Writer%29) to copy the content of the response input stream and cache it to a file.
- You could [enable gzipping of the request and the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573391/android-http-communication-should-use-accept-encoding-gzip).
- You also need to close properly the `HttpConnection` in the finally block, [you can consume the entity of the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775618/httpclient-4-0-1-how-to-release-connection) to achieve this.

Comment: Snicolas, could you please elaborate more on what it means to consume the entity? I read some of the [Apache documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) on this but still I don't get what "consuming an entity" means. Thanks! D

Comment: Sure I followed the link first :-). I simply don't understand what "consuming an entity" means. Does it involve any filling up/emptying of buffers? What is the underlying mechanism being triggered by `response.getEntity().consumeContent();`? I still didn't get around to implement this so I still get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: AndroidHttpClient created and never closed`, which is a good reminder to do so.

Comment: response.getEntity().consumeContent(); yes, this is the point. Do it in a try catch

Comment: I've added `response.getEntity().consumeContent();` and `httpClient.close();` - I believe those are two different things, releasing two different types of resources. What do you think? (I added my most recent code above)