# Retrieve the http code of the response in java

Tags: java, android, http

I have the following code for make a post to an url an retrieve the response as a String. But I'd like to get also the HTTP response code (404,503, etc). Where can I recover it?
I've tried with the methods offered by the HttpReponse class but didn't find it.

Thanks

```
public static String post(String url, List<BasicNameValuePair> postvalues) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        if ((postvalues == null)) {
            postvalues = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        }
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postvalues, "UTF-8"));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return requestToString(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}


private static String requestToString(HttpResponse response) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line + "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        result = str.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = "Error";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` just after `httpclient.execute` so if code is `HttpStatus.SC_OK` you call `requestToString` in other cases you have error :)

Comment: @Selvin - how about making that comment an answer? It's correct btw, +1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592843/android-how-get-the-status-code-of-an-httpclient-request

Comment: @Addev see my edit in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify your code like this:

```
//...
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
  //edit: there is already function for this
  return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
} else {
  //Houston we have a problem
  //we should do something with bad http status
  return null;
}
```

EDIT: just one more thing ...
instead of `requestToString(..);` you can use `EntityUtils.toString(..);`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```