# Starting my first android app. How can I easily test if the server has received a message?

Tags: java, php, android

I am experienced with Java and have some experience with PHP (the server scripting language I will be using unless anybody tells me I shouldn't for some reason.  I want to just send a string via POST to the server.  Because there is not actually a webpage being created, I can't just echo the string if it is received.  How should I test if the string was received by the server?

Edit:
After further research, it seems like echo doesn't just print to a browser, it sends a string through the http connection to whatever is connected to the php page.  I should then be able to echo a response and receive it through an input string on the Java end.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `echo`, as you mentioned, but the more common and reusable method of debugging PHP as you progress is the use of `error_log()`. You can view its output on the PHP server in the php.log file, commonly found at `/tmp/php.log`.

You can watch this file in real-time via the Unix command `tail -f /tmp/php.log`.

Further, you can output various forms of data by calling it with `print_r()` like `error_log(print_r($data, TRUE));`.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there was some kind of log.  That sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: It seems that I don't have php error log configured and I can't seem to find the configuration files.  It should be somewhere in /etc, right?  But I can't even find /etc.  I don't have much linux experience, could you help me out?  I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, check your php.ini to see where your error log is set up for. The ini should be in /etc.

Comment: That's the issue though, I can't find any system files at all.  No /etc, no /tmp, no /var

Comment: Oh nevermind, its been a while since I used Linux.  Found it.

Comment: Cheers. Best of luck and godspeed with PHP. If you're from the Java world, give HHVM a look. You'll feel right at home.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be properly sending back [Responde codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) in your php scripts.

Please check: [How to send a status code in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797274/how-to-send-a-status-code-in-php-without-maintaining-an-array-of-status-names) and [Android: How get the status-code of an HttpClient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592843/android-how-get-the-status-code-of-an-httpclient-request).

Comment: This would be ideal in a full application, but at this time the OP is just starting out, so getting a handle on proper debugging is a good first step.